# Html django update variable without refreshing the whole page

Tags: javascript, html, django

Whenever a page is refreshed, the scroll reset to the initial position and so it's uncomfortable for the user to go back at the position he was looking at. So I would like to change the value of the variable qdelete whenever the delete button is clicked without refreshing the whole page:
My html file:
    {% for q in questions %}

```
        <tr>
            <td>
             <div align= Center>
             {% if qdelete == forloop.counter %}
            <div align= Center>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="qyesbtn" name="qyesbtn" value="qyesbtn_{{q.id}}">Yes &raquo;</button>
            </div>
            <div align= Center>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" id="qnobtn" name="qnobtn" value="qnobtn">No &raquo;</button> 
            </div>
             {% else %}
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" name="qid"  onclick="qdelete=forloop.counter" value="{{forloop.counter}}">Delete &raquo;</button>
             {% endif %}
             </div>
            </td>

        </tr>
           {% endfor %}
<script>
function SetDelete(num){
    qdelete = num
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to call the SetDelete() javascript function but it doesn't work. Any advice it's appreciated.

Comment: I can't follow exactly what you want, but it looks for me you need to have a look on some ajax techniques

Comment: Django does not help you here. You need to do this with javascript and as rwx pointed out with ajax if you need server interaction.